# Express redirect to static html if available else to custom path

Tags: node.js, express, redirect

How to redirect to static *html if available in public folder & to 404 if not available.

```
var _version = 'v1';

// redirect to a.html
app.get(_version + '/a.html', (req, res)  => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(_dirname, 'public', 'htmls', 'a.html'));
});

// redirect to b.html
app.get(_version + '/b.html', (req, res)  => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(_dirname, 'public', 'htmls', 'b.html'));
});

// redirect to c.html
app.get(_version + '/c.html', (req, res)  => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(_dirname, 'public', 'htmls', 'c.html'));
});

// redirect to someRandom.html
app.get(_version + '/someRandom.html', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(_dirname, 'public', 'htmls', 'someRandom.html'));
});

// else redirect to index.html
app.get(_version + '/*.html', (req, res)  => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(_dirname, 'public', 'htmls', 'index.html'));
});
```

How do I combine the first four request to redirect to corresponding *.html, so that if file exists it has to redirect to that file, else to index.html.

**NOTE:** I am handling all other `404` & `500` requests separately.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this quite simply using express.static

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(_dirname, 'public/htmls')));
```

Or you can change your four routes into one route using parameters:

```
app.get(_version + '/:filename', (req, res)  => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(_dirname, 'public', 'htmls', req.params.filename));
});
```